# how to change marker with scroll the recyclerView

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-recyclerview, google-maps-markers

I want change `map` `marker` with scroll the `recyclerView`. But with use `onScrollStateChanged` method and set my `LatLng`, can't change marker and move camera!

Now, how to change marker with scroll the `RecyclerView`?

And, What is the best practice to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: can you share your code to get recyclerview scroll event ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code to set marker and animate camera should look something like this. Hope this helps

```
private void setLocationToMap(LatLng latLng) {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            MarkerOptions myLocation = new MarkerOptions();
            myLocation.position(latLng);
            googleMap.clear();
            googleMap.addMarker(myLocation);
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            myMarker = latLng;
        }
    }
```